# Why crash-free Statistics not appearing in some app flavours?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm currently migrating Crashlytics from Fabric to Firebase. I generated some crashes for all my app flavours to test it. When I checked Firebase, the crashes appear listed on all flavours' tables but not all of the crash-free statistics show the graph. Some flavours do, some don't. The ones that don't, show the "make sure your App has Google Analytics... latest Crashlytics SDK" message.

As a side note, the crash-free stats appear on Fabric just fine for all app flavours.

Versions:

- Firebase-core 16.0.1
- Crashlytics 2.9.5
- Google services 3.2.1
- Fabric 1.+

Answer (score 1):

The crash free statistics chart can take a day or two to actually display, as it requires Firebase to have received and processed a certain amount of data.

I found adding Firebase Analytics and using the app to trigger a few screen views resolved the issue.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Crash free users are showing for 2 of my app flavour, not showing for one. It is showing "To see this data, make sure your app has Google Analytics for Firebase and the latest Firebase Crashlytics SDK." I am  using latest sdk version for both crashlytics and analytics.